# HQL - difference between two same queries

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Why does this query work normal:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Table tab");
```

And this query:

```
Query query = session
  .createQuery("select tab.col1, tab.col2, tab.col3 from Table tab");
```

And that's what I'm doing with both queries:

```
dataList = query.list();
for (Table item : dataList)
{
  System.out.println(item.getCol1();
}
```

reports:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to table.Table
at test.TestCriteria.main(TestCriteria.java:35)
```

Could you help?

Table is normally mapped in entity bean and all the columns are correct.

Comment: What are you doing after the query? The error is happening in your code, not in NH.

Comment: I've changed my question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in the *second* `query`, the result is a `List<Object[]>`:

```
Object[] row = (Object[]) dataList.get(i);
Object col1Value = row[0];
Object col2Value = row[1];
Object col3Value = row[2];
```

I have this guess observing `Ljava.lang.Object;` in the exception trace.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't to iterate it using list()?

Comment: You iterate over `dataList` and each item you get from `dataList` is now in turn an `Object[]` that should be iterated over again to access each column value.

Answer (score 2):

The result of query `select tab.col1, tab.col2, tab.col3` returns list of object array which contains the selected fields i.e col1, col2 & col3.

Then from the object array, you can extract fields by their index.

```
for(Object[] field : dataList){

    col1 = field[0]; //-- Casting accordingly
     col2 = field[1]; 
     col3 = field[2]; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found the similar answer before but I didn't believe it :(

Comment: @gaffcz You're welcome. It might happen that both have posted simultaneously or have little time difference.