# Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return

Tags: jpa

I am using the following JPA query and i am getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return  Exception.

```
TypedQuery<RaBdrRating> uQuery = 
  (TypedQuery<RaBdrRating>)entityManager.createQuery("
     SELECT r.activePackage,SUM(r.duration),SUM(r.charge),COUNT(r) 
     FROM RaBdrRating r WHERE r.callType = :callType 
     and r.startDate between :startDate and :endDate 
     GROUP BY r.activePackage",RaBdrRating.class);

uQuery.setParameter("callType", model.getCallType());
uQuery.setParameter("startDate",startDate);
uQuery.setParameter("endDate",endDate);
List<RaBdrRating> listOfPackages = uQuery.getResultList();
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong in my query.....I am new to JPA and i am not getting what is the problem and strucked up here.If any one have idea please tell me.

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010154/366964 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536802/366964

Answer (score 4):

I go the same error:
Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type

Solution:

Having a Query like this:

```
Select e.fieldA, e.fieldB, e.fieldC From Entity e
```

You have to declare a constructor with the parameters specified on query:

```
    package somepackage;

    public class Entity {
    ...
       public class Entity() {}

       public class Entity(Type fieldA, Type fieldB, Type fieldC) {
           this.fieldA = fieldA;
           this.fieldB = fieldB;
           this.fieldC = fieldC;
       }
    ....
    }
```

Finally, modify your query

```
Select NEW somepackage.Entity(e.fieldA, e.fieldB, e.fieldC) From Entity e
```

You are indicating how the objectes will be created.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be this bug: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6304

It is apparently fixed in version 4.1.5.