# Hibernate Projection select statement causes Internal Server Error

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm running into an Internal Server Error (nothing written to Tomcat logs, other than 500 error) when I try to run a specified select statement in Hibernate. When running a traditional simple `select` statement, I have no issues.

I'm logging the hibernate queries to my console. The hibernate query that works fine is just a traditional select statement 
(`select x from Entity x`):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        trumpialis0_.TLDLID as TLDLID1_0_,
        trumpialis0_.TLDLDNM as TLDLDNM2_0_,
        trumpialis0_.TLDLMSG as TLDLMSG3_0_,
        trumpialis0_.TLDLNAM as TLDLNAM4_0_,
        trumpialis0_.TLDLDAB as TLDLDAB5_0_,
        trumpialis0_.TLDLSTS as TLDLSTS6_0_ 
    from
        LIBRARY.TABLE trumpialis0_ 
    where
        trumpialis0_.TLDLSTS='W'
```

The hibernate query when running a `select x.property... from Entity x`

```
   Hibernate: 
        select
            trumpialis0_.TLDLDNM as col_0_0_ 
        from
            LIBRARY.TABLE trumpialis0_ 
        where
            trumpialis0_.TLDLSTS='W'
```

the Java running the select is: `rows = em.createQuery("select x.displayName from X where x.webStatus = 'W'").getResultList();`

My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE", schema = "LIBRARY")
@XmlRootElement
public class X {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
    private String webStatus;
    private String messagesPerMonth;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TLDLID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ....
```

For what it's worth, I can run a JPA-QL query in Intellij and get back just the columns I'd like, however they seem to lose their column name when I do so.

Is there a way I can select just certain properties? I don't need to return everything, and really don't want to cast to a "return object" or something like that.

Comment: so, if you just do a division by zero, do you see any useful information in the log, or do you also just receive a plain 500 with no explanation?

Comment: Where should I attempt a division by 0?

Comment: in any place where you are sure it will be executed.  Possibly right before "the Java running the select".

Comment: Yes, it complains. I can do other erroneous things and it will be more helpful with the problem.

Comment: Wow.  I don't know what's the problem then.  Let's see if anyone else has any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was multidimensional.

First off, I wasn't quite using the correct syntax inside of my select statement. What I really needed to do was create a new Entity from the results of the existing one. I finally dawned on this with Google, and realizing that stepping through the debugger; my code didn't fail until **AFTER** I wanted to do something with the results, not the results themselves.

```
rows = em.createQuery("select NEW com.example.entities.Entity(list.id, list.name, list.displayName, list.messsagesPerMonth) from Entity list where list.webStatus = 'W'").getResultList();
```

Now, in order to have this work correctly, Intellij was smart enough to warn me that [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245397/cannot-create-typedquery-for-query-with-more-than-one-return) such Constructor [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807496/error-cannot-create-typedquery-for-query-with-more-than-one-return) in the Entity, so I had to create a constructor based off of these values, and add this to my other generated-Entity code.

Finally, the code bombing off Hibernate without any helpful debugging at all was totally my inexperience showing with OO.

Although null values are allowed to be set to the Entity properties, when you're dealing with a legacy database that returns strings based on their entire length, you're eager to tidy up those strings inside of the Entity, as they contain many blank spaces after the trip back from the DB.

Unfortunately the way I was doing this was just a simple `property.trim()` on the return statement of `getName()` et. al. methods.

```
public String getMesssagesPerMonth() {
    return messagesPerMonth;
}
```

What I needed was something a bit more robust, with error checking so that it wouldn't try to `trim()` a `null` value if a property was set to `null`.

```
public String getMesssagesPerMonth() {
    if (messagesPerMonth != null) {
        return messagesPerMonth.trim();
    } else {
        return messagesPerMonth;
    }
}
```